# Align center code (wrong rendered output?) not working in MediaWiki

Tags: html, html-table, mediawiki

I noticed that the `<td align="center">` code works differently on the MediaWiki.org page and the en.wikipedia.org page. I type the same following test code on the both wikis:

- http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/User:Scottie33/sandbox
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Scottie33/sandbox

Source (test) code:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      test test test test test test

      test

      <table border="1"><tr><td>
      [[File:Information_icon.svg|20px]]
      </td></tr></table>

      test
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

**Why the MediaWiki.org page produce following (wrong) code:**

```
<td style="text-align: center;">
```

**instead (expected) of this:**

```
<td align="center">
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? Know why that happens on mw.org, or get a solution that works on mw.org?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `wgHtml5`is enabled (which is enabled by default in the MediaWiki software, but disabled on most Wikimedia Foundation wikis, and has recently been enabled on mediawiki.org) then the Html processor in MediaWiki strips presentational attributes such as these, and replaces them with a rough equivalent inline style attribute.

That system has a bug (filed as [bug #36495 (bugzilla.wikimedia.org)](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36495)) in scenarios such as these, because text-align or float alone doesn't cover all of it.

See also:

- [$wgHtml5](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHtml5)
- [$wgCleanupPresentationalAttributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgCleanupPresentationalAttributes)

But so much for the cause of the problem. Back to the issue at hand, the short version is: those attributes are deprecated, and you're best off not using them in the first place.

Instead use CSS. Or, in this particular example (as Bergi mentioned earlier), there is an alternative method that is more appropriate: Use the `|center|` keyword in the `[[File:` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for your good explanation! :) I changed the `$wgCleanupPresentationalAttributes` parameter to `false` and my own Wiki works as before upgrading to 1.19 version.

Comment: For the record, we've fixed [this bug](https://bugzilla.wikimedia.org/show_bug.cgi?id=36495) in the next release of the software (MediaWiki 1.20). It has already been deployed on Wikipedia sites.

Answer (score 3):

The wikis seem to run with different <s>[configs for HTML Tidy](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgUseTidy)</s> values of [$wgCleanupPresentationalAttributes](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgCleanupPresentationalAttributes), which will correct the deprecated styling html attributes in favor of css.

Yet, `align="center"` and `style="text-align:center"` don't show exactly the same behaviour. While the align attribute affects both inline elements, block elements and afaik itself, the css property only aligns inline elements (text). To align block elements, you'd use the margin-property.

Correct markup:

```
{| style="text-align:center; border:1px solid;"
| test test test test

test
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
[[File:Information icon.svg|20px]]
</div>
|}
```

or, even easier:

```
[[File:Information icon.svg|center|20px|border]]
```

Comment: The Tidy settings are globally set at Wikimedia, there are no overrides for MediaWiki.org. This difference is caused by the stripping of deprecated presentational attributes in HTML5 mode (wgHtml5).

Comment: @Bergi: Your code not working in 100% that I expected, because only image is centered and not **whole content** in a table data cell (td). See: [screen](http://i.imgur.com/qkOVV.png).

But, many, many thanks for your help! :-)

Comment: @Scottie: As I said, to center the table you will need to apply the styles on the table. [demo](http://www.mediawiki.org/w/index.php?diff=547854&oldid=547794).